# After becomeFirstResponder textField doesn't send events to delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, textfield, becomefirstresponder, resignfirstresponder

can anybody help me in such situation:

I have SigninController class with two textFields (as Outlets) txtLogin and txtPassword:

when I filled txtLogin, I call [txtPassword becomeFirstResponder] to pass input focus to next field (return button works fine in txtLogin), but Return button doesn't work in txtPassword and I can't dismiss keyboard in this case. What did I write wrong ?

Example code:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == txtLogin) {
        [txtLogin resignFirstResponder];      //Works as I think
        [txtPassword becomeFirstResponder];   // txtPassword gets focus
    } else {
        [self signinClick];  //Never enter here
    }
    return YES;
}


- (IBAction)signinClick
{
    NSLog(@"Signin Clicked");
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [txtPassword resignFirstResponder];
    ..........
}
```

Comment: did you set delegate of textfield ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have forgot to set the **delegate** of *txtPassword* correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was my stupid fault.  Sorry - couldn't click UP arrow for your answer (I'm newb here and have no enought repuation to vote)

Answer (score 0):

specify

urtextfieldobject.delegate=self;

then urViewcontroller.h

@interface urViewcontroller

make sure both of them